# Pyspark - generate a dates column having all the days between two given dates and add it to an existing dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am relatively new to pyspark. I want to generate a dataframe column with dates between two given dates (constants) and add this column to an existing dataframe. What will be the efficient way?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
df_add_column = df.withColumn("repeat", expr("split(repeat(',', diffDays), ',')")).select("*", posexplode("repeat").alias('DATE', "val")) .drop("repeat", "val", "diffDays").withColumn('DATE', expr("date_add('2018-01-01', 'DATE')"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#sequence) function to generate the dates then explode. Example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,)], ["id"])

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "date", 
    F.explode(F.expr("sequence(to_date('2021-02-01'), to_date('2021-02-08'), interval 1 day)"))
)

df1.show()

#+---+----------+
#| id|      date|
#+---+----------+
#|  1|2021-02-01|
#|  1|2021-02-02|
#|  1|2021-02-03|
#|  1|2021-02-04|
#|  1|2021-02-05|
#|  1|2021-02-06|
#|  1|2021-02-07|
#|  1|2021-02-08|
#+---+----------+
```

Comment: Just a thought, what if i want to create a new dataframe(with no columns) and add this date column so that i have only ONE date column? Any ideas?

Comment: you can use the code from @blackbishop and then select only the date column:

df1 = df1.select('date')